# is it possible? share TV over LAN via raspberry pi (as server)

Tags: networking

I'm kinda stuck at an idea and was hoping to get some input / help on this.

What I'd like is to connect my TV cable to my raspberry Pi (perhaps via a USB device) and to configure it to allow other computers on my network to connect to my Pi and watch TV as a client.

Would this even work with the raspberry Pi? or would it not have enough power to process the signal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, I've used tvheadend in combination with a USB DVB-s receiver, works fine.

https://tvheadend.org/

for a list of supported adapters look here:

http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_TV_Tuners_and_DVB_devices

There's basically no processing power required, TvHeadend just passes the MPEG TS/mp4 stream from your DVB capture device to the network...

The pi gets into trouble when watching 2 or 3 HD streams (720p) at the same time.
I guess it's because of the Bandwidth needed and the Ethernet and USB are on the same BUS on the Pi, the data pretty much travels back and forth in the pi multiple times.